Invalid client in django-oauth-toolkit v2 that was valid in v1
I'm running seasonal upgrades on a project and noticed django-oauth-toolkit stayed a 1.7.1 last time.
The upgrade to 2.x turns two tests from 200 to 401, invalid_client.
One of these tests looks like this;
@pytest.fixture
def oauth_data(db):
    test_region = Region.objects.create(
        name="MyRegion", iso_code_short="MYR", iso_code_long="MYREG"
    )
    app_owner = USER_MODEL(
        username="app-owner",
        email="owner@somewhere.com",
        gender="M",
        date_of_birth="1970-1-1",
        region=test_region,
        first_name="John",
        last_name="Doe",
    )
    app_owner.set_password("password")
    app_owner.save()

    app_redirects = "http://site1.com/return\r\nhttp://site2.com/back"
    app = Application.objects.create(
        name="My Test Client",
        client_id="test-app",
        client_secret="password",
        client_type=Application.CLIENT_CONFIDENTIAL,
        authorization_grant_type=Application.GRANT_PASSWORD,
        user=app_owner,
        skip_authorization=True,
        redirect_uris=app_redirects,
    )
    return {"app": app, "app_owner": app_owner}


# some test class here...

    def (
        self, oauth_data, client, settings
    ):
        mixin = AccessTokenGeneratorMixin()
        tokens = mixin.get_access_token(oauth_data["app"], oauth_data["user"])

        url = reverse("oauth2_provider:token")
        response = client.post(
            url,
            data={
                "client_id": oauth_data["app"].client_id,
                "client_secret": oauth_data["app"].client_secret,
                "grant_type": "refresh_token",
                "refresh_token": tokens["refresh_token"],
            },
        )
        assert 200 == response.status_code

Is there something in v2 (that I've missed in the release notes) that invalidates this fixture to create an invalid client!?

This was a case of not reading someone else's code very well.
In version 2, client secrets are hashed in the database, therefore the hashed value isn't going to correctly identify the client application when doing;
"client_secret": oauth_data["app"].client_secret,

The solution here is to use the same value that sets the application's client_secret when sending the data to the token endpoint.
@pytest.fixture
def oauth_data(db):
    client_secret = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
    test_region = Region.objects.create(
        name="MyRegion", iso_code_short="MYR", iso_code_long="MYREG"
    )
    app_owner = USER_MODEL(
        username="app-owner",
        email="owner@somewhere.com",
        gender="M",
        date_of_birth="1970-1-1",
        region=test_region,
        first_name="John",
        last_name="Doe",
    )
    app_owner.set_password("password")
    app_owner.save()

    app_redirects = "http://site1.com/return\r\nhttp://site2.com/back"
    app = Application.objects.create(
        name="My Test Client",
        client_id="test-app",
        client_secret=client_secret,
        client_type=Application.CLIENT_CONFIDENTIAL,
        authorization_grant_type=Application.GRANT_PASSWORD,
        user=app_owner,
        skip_authorization=True,
        redirect_uris=app_redirects,
    )
    return {
        "app": app,
        "app_owner": app_owner,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
    }

# into a class

    def test_oauth2_access_token_renewal_format(
        self, oauth_data, client, settings
    ):
        mixin = AccessTokenGeneratorMixin()
        tokens = mixin.get_access_token(oauth_data["app"], oauth_data["user"])

        url = reverse("oauth2_provider:token")
        response = client.post(
            url,
            data={
                "client_id": oauth_data["app"].client_id,
                "client_secret": oauth_data["client_secret"],
                "grant_type": "refresh_token",
                "refresh_token": tokens["refresh_token"],
            },
        )
        assert 200 == response.status_code

